Is it a good idea to incorporate a feature into the loss function when training a neural network model that does regression?
When training a neural network that does regression, assuming I have 3 features called "a", "b", and "c". The corresponding target is called "d". In theory, when trained properly, this mode would use "a", "b", "c" to successfully predict the value of "d". However, since the feature "c" is calculated from "a" and "d" during training, and therefore, during inference, "c" is not available.
Is it a good idea that I move feature "c" into the loss function, so the model is indirectly trained on it? For example, the loss function would be something like MSE(y_pred, y_true) + penalty_term * c?

If you calculate c from a and b during training, and have a and b available during inference, what stops you from calculating c from a and b again during inference? Also, simply adding a term to the loss that apparently does not depend on the prediction and the actual of the target means that it is irrelevant to your model, because it can't be influenced by changing the model output. Perhaps you could give a few more details of what you are actually trying to achieve?
